# Rewrite damped wave equation as diagonal first order system

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Can we rewrite the wave equation with damping (aka. telegrapher's equation)
$$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} + a u_t = 0 $$
as a first order diagonal system of two equations?

Comment: What are your ideas about it?

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2601371/418542), where does it get you?

Answer (score 0):

First assume there were two first order equations
$$f(u,u_x)=u_t$$
$$g(u,u_t)=u_x$$
so that
$$\frac{\partial f(u,u_x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g(u,u_t)}{\partial t}$$
would become
$$c^2 u_{xx} = u_{tt} + a u_t$$
So you can say
\begin{align}
f(u,u_x)&=c^2u_x+C_1x+C_2\\[2ex]
g(u,u_t)&=u_t+au+C_1t+C_3
\end{align}
And the system of first order equations can be
\begin{cases}
c^2u_x-u_t+C_1x+C_2&=0\\[2ex]
-u_x+u_t+au+C_1t+C_3&=0
\end{cases}
And then you can make those diagonal from there.